# UmbracoTemplateview inheritance in master.cshtml overrides UmbracoViewPage<customModel> in blog.cshtml

Tags: razor, umbraco, umbraco7

So I need to be able to set the title of my site to the page the visitor is on so in my Master.cshtml I have

```
@inherits UmbracoTemplatePage
....
<title>@Model.Content.Name</title>
```

Works great.

Now I want to pass my custom blogpost model to my blogview which has Master.cshtml as layout

```
    @inherits UmbracoViewPage<Umbraco_Blog.Models.BlogPost[]>
    @{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
      }
```

and in my controller i return a BlogPost[]

```
return CurrentTemplate(blogposts);
```

But this just gives me this error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'Umbraco_Blog.Models.BlogPost[]', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel'.

If i remove the layout, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get around this is to make your BlogPost model inherit from RenderModel. If you take this approach you will need to call the RenderModel constructor with an instance of IPublishedContent which you can do like so:

```
public BlogPost() : base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent)
{
}
```

Another solution is to strongly type your layout to a base class model e.g.

```
@model MyBaseViewModel
```

then change your BlogPost model to inherit from that base model, and define the model type of the view using

```
@model BlogPost
```

Note that if you adopt this approach you lose the helper properties such as the UmbracoHelper etc.